# rewrite define macro as c++ code?

Tags: c++, macros

How i can write this macro as c++ code?

```
extern bool distribution_test_server;
bool distribution_test_server = false;
#define GetGoldMultipler() (distribution_test_server ? 3 : 1)
```

And one more question, what is the vale of the macros if `distribution_test_server = false;`

Soo if `distribution_test_server` is `false`... then the macro it's not used?

Example i have this :

```
#define GetGoldMultipler() (distribution_test_server ? 3 : 1)
```

Comment: The macro is C++ code. What do you need to change?

Answer (score 2):

You can write it as an inline function:

```
inline int GetGoldMultipler()
{
    return distribution_test_server ? 3 : 1;
}
```

If `distribution_test_server` is false, the multiplier returned is 1.

Answer (score 1):

It's *already* C++ code, but I assume you want to rewrite it as a function:

```
int GetGoldMultiplier() {return distribution_test_server ? 3 : 1;}
```

If `distribution_test_server` is false then the gold multiplier will be 1; that's how `?:` works. (If the first part is true, the second part is returned; else the third part)

Answer (score 0):

The macro will replace any place it you code where there is the symbol GetGoldMultiplier() with the expression "distribution_test_server ? 3 : 1" And this happens as a precompilation step so before the code is interpreted. This also means that there never will be a function GetColdMultiplier() even if your code looks like it is calling it.

This means that if distribution_test_server is false then the expression will always be 1. if it is true the value will always be 3.

That is because the expression

```
  val = a ? 3 : 1
```

is a short hand syntax inherited from C for the code

```
  if (a)
  {
      val = 3;
  }
  else
  {
      val = 1;
  }
```

You could so of achieve the same thing with an inline function but inline is only a compiler suggestion the macro is guaranteed to do this. But if inlining is preformed, then the result will be equivalent.

```
  inline int GetGoldMultipler()
  {
      return distribution_test_server ? 3 : 1;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

What is defined in this macro is what we call a ternary expression.

It's basically an "if" condition concatenated, this expression can be resumed as :

```
int MyFunction()
{
    if(ditribution_test_server == true)
    {
        return 3;
    }
    else
    {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

more on ternary conditions : http://www.cprogramming.com/reference/operators/ternary-operator.html

Now the macro is something completely different. When you define a macro and use it in your code, the compiler replace the macro by what you wrote on the right side.

For example :

```
#define MY_MACRO 8
int a = MY_MACRO;
```

actually translate to:

```
int a = 8;
```

more on macros : http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/preprocessor/

So in your code `#define GetGoldMultiplier() (distribution_test_server ? 3 : 1)` defines a macro named `GetGoldMultiplier()` (which is NOT a function !) which upon use will be replaced by `(distribution_test_server ? 3 : 1)` which can be interpreted as what I wrote before.